# Can't convert HTML to editorState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

Well, what i'm trying to do is to create editorState with given HTML, but as things go complex(like nested divs or table tags) editor doesn't seem to render them correctly;

Here's my code:

```
const blocks = htmlToDraft(props.html);
const { contentBlocks, entityMap } = blocks;
const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocks, entityMap);
const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
```

For simple examples like `<h1>Hey</h1>` it's totally fine, but as I try something like

```
<body style="--theme-text-color: #757575; --theme-secondary-text-color: 
hsla(0, 0%, 46%, 0.32); --theme-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;">
 <div data-x-div- type="html">
  <div data-x-div-type="body">
   <div style="padding: 10px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; word- 
    wrap:break-word;"> 
     <div style="border:4px solid #f09650; padding: 15px; width: 370px;"> 
      <h2 style="margin: 5px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.4;">33</h2> 
      <span>Starts at ... </span><br> 
      <span>Calendar: sample@mail</span><br><br>
      <span></span><br> 
    </div> 
    <p style="color:#667766; width: 400px; font-size: 10px;">This message 
    arrived to your <a href="mailto:sample@mail">sample@mail</a> account 
    because you  ordered event notification</p> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

editor simply parse it to string and doesn't show the HTML properly.

I've tried thousands of different ways how to fix it, all things like `import-html-draft-js`, `state-from-html` and other side libs, but they had no effect. So now I'm really desperate and hope to get at least a hint.

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: I’m using react-draft-wysiwyg: https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg